# The port 'COM11' does not exist. Specified port is not open

Tags: unity-game-engine, serial-port

I have been using Unity and teensy to perform serial communication for quite some time. And it has been working fine.
Now I changed my teensy board and thus the COM Port has changed on it.
Teensy is communicating perfectly in arduino and sending all the right signals when checked in serial monitor. But I am getting this error in unity.

```
> IOException: The port `COM11' does not exist.
System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream.ReportIOError (System.String optional_arg)
System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream..ctor (System.String port_name, Int32 

baud_rate, Int32 data_bits, Parity parity, StopBits sb, Boolean dtr_enable, Boolean rts_enable, Handshake hs, Int32 read_timeout, Int32 write_timeout, Int32 read_buffer_size, Int32 write_buffer_size)
    (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.Ports.WinSerialStream:.ctor (string,int,int,System.IO.Ports.Parity,System.IO.Ports.StopBits,bool,bool,System.IO.Ports.Handshake,int,int,int,int)
    System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open ()
```

Initially the com ports were single digit values such as COM4 or COM8 etc. But since I started getting twodigit COM Ports I started facing this problem. If I connect a teensy again with a single digit com port it works fine but does not detect COM50 etc.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If this is Windows OS then try to specify the COM port name as \\.\COM11

```
myPort= new SerialPort("\\\\.\\COM11",9600);
```

NOTES: This syntax also works for ports COM1 through COM9. Certain boards will let you choose the port names yourself. This syntax works for those names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames() to see what names does the OS use for current COM ports. (I'm not sure if you're talking about .NET, but if you do this helps)

Comment: this indeed lists up the comports, but it shows COM11 with the exact same problem like OP again. Helen's solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
foreach(string str in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Existing COM port: {0}", str));
}
```

For know the ports available